# Jquery .html update value

Tags: jquery

I have the following div tag within my html file:

```
<div id='attendeelist'></div>
```

I am using the following Jquery to the value of it but nothing seems to be happening. Any idea. I thought .html would do the trick

```
tble = '<h1>test</h1>';
$('#attendeelist').html(tble);
```

Comment: Check: a. the div exists, b. the page has rendered completely and c. that you've got the cASinG On tHE naMe right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure to wrap in the ready function?

```
$(function(){
       var tble = '<h1>test</h1>';
       $('#attendeelist').html(tble);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Is `#attendeelist` yet available when the code runs? If not, then wrap your code into a function that is executed when the DOM is loaded:

```
$(function(){
   var tble = '<h1>test</h1>';
   $('#attendeelist').html(tble);
});
```

Comment: might want to do `var tble` for scoping ^_^ `+1`

Comment: Indeed, thanks for that! *Edited*. That saved me the 3 seconds that I was before your answer. :-)

Comment: hehe that's what it seems lol